Is the little thing on the GPU supposed to be in the pcie slot?
My PC crashed and when i opened the case i saw the the GPU is a little bent and this part of the slot is not in the slot, for reference the gpu is a GTX 750 TI 2 gigabytes and i don't know if this part is supposed to be in or not
the picture is showing which part is not in the slot


Hello, there is no image

Please explain what you mean by “this part […] is not in the slot”.

The part of the board you are pointing is required for the board to function.

Yes, that part is supposed to be in the matching part of the connector on the motherboard.
Lets take a look it it by borrowing a picture from Wikipedia. Depicted is PCIe x16. You can see that it comes in two parts. The first part is always  present, the second part can vary in size depending if you have an PCIe card, x1, x4, x8 or x16. But the first part is always present and should always be plugged in.
I am surprised tbat it even booted without this part inserted, since according to the logic no card is inserted (the pin 'PRESENT' is not inserted, so the computer should assume that the whole slot is empty).

